# SQLite3 - Search on text field with \0 binary data

Tags: sqlite

I index a file in a SQLite DB.

I create my table with this:

```
CREATE TABLE Record (RecordID INTEGER,Data TEXT,PRIMARY KEY (RecordID))
```

I read a file, and for each line I add a row on the table.
Each line can have binary data at end. It's not a problem for many chars, but **\0** char make a problem.

If I have a line like this : "My data \0with binary".

When I try to get data after the **\0** not worked (`SELECT substr(Data, 11, 5) FROM Record` return an empty string or `SELECT substr(Data, 4, 10) FROM Record` return data)

When I try to search a data (`SELECT Data FROM Record WHERE Data LIKE '%binar%'`) return 0 rows returned.

How can I solve this problem ? I try to replace \0 by an other char sequence, but it's not a good idea because can I have this sequence in my file.

Thank you

Comment: If you know where binary data starts, you can convert them to hex data and save it like that. when searching, you can convert your search string to hex and compare hex values.

Comment: Thank for you answer. But I see that is very slow. My files can be huge (2 or 3GB) and binary data position is random (can I not have  or can I have one or multi binary data)

Comment: You can search for 'blob' datatype of sqlite. That type may suit for your need. You can save all file lines as binary.